# Isomorphisms between $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathbb{Q}^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question:  Show that $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ where both are additive groups under the usual matrix and coordinatewise addition, respectively.

I know to show something is an isomorphism, you must first show it is a homomorphism by showing that there exists a function such that $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$.  And then to show it is isomorphic, you must show that said function is bijective, however I am uncertain of how to do it with these two groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
An isomorphism of the additive groups only needs to respect the addition
$$f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$$
Thus show that for the canonical Isomorphism
$$f(A) = \pmatrix{A_{11}\\A_{21}\\A_{12}\\A_{22}}$$
$$f(A+_{M_2(\mathbb Q)}B) = f(A) +_{\mathbb Q^4} f(B)$$
With both additions element-wise.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you don't need to worry about multiplication. Since the question only asks about a *group* isomorphism, there is only one operation to concern yourself with.

As is, if you use the (reasonably obvious) multiplication operation on $\mathbb{Q}^{\oplus 4}$---that is, the one given by
$$
(a,b,c,d) \cdot_{\mathbb{Q}^{\oplus 4}} (e,f,g,h) = (ae, bf, cg, dh)
$$
then it is not a homomorphism, which is probably worthwhile to check. However, this isn't relevant, as the question is only about the category of groups, and not of rings.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it isn't a ring; it is a ring, but it isn't a field.

Comment: Yeah sorry mixed the terms. I should drink some coffee.

Comment: You should always drink some coffee!